# How to add .dll file in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have a project where in i have implemented the AutoSearch functionality using asp.net TextBox and AJAX AutoComplete extender. I also have some javascript written for AutoComplete extender.
I want to make this file as a .dll file and use it in another projects. How should i make a .dll out of this project?
Please help me to do this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a Class Library of the part you want to reuse.

After that, simply go to your main project and add a reference to the class libary output (the dll file)